# How to import color scheme into Spyder 4?

Tags: spyder, color-scheme

Is there any way to import a color theme into Spyder? I need a theme other than the ready ones in the Preference, something like Ayu Dark theme in Pycharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is not possible at moment (April 2020), but we're working to provide that functionality for Spyder 5, to be released in 2021.